# stuck with WordNet relations in nested list in prolog

Tags: prolog, nlp, wordnet

I would like to do an approximate match using wordNet relations, 
So there are two items approximately match if
  (i) the head of one subsumes the head of the other according to wordnet
  (ii) (a) the first dtr of each approximately match
       (b) we skip over the first dtr of the second tree and try again

To do this neatly, you want approxmatch and approxmatchdtrs.

```
[love, [peter], [susan], [in, [january]] |- [like, [peter], [susan]]
```

I tried to solve it this way but it is not working:

```
subsynset([] ,_).

subsynset([H0 | ARGS0], [H1 | ARGS1]) :-
    wordnetsubsumes(H0, H1),
    subsynset(ARGS0,ARGS1).

subsynset(L, [_ | ARGS]):-
    subsynset(L, ARGS).


wordnetsubsumes(H0, H0).

wordnetsubsumes(H0, H1):-
    \+list(
    s(I,_,H0,_,_,_),
    (hyp(I, J) ->
    s(J,_,Hyp,_,_,_),
    Hyp = H1 ;
    subsynset(Hyp, H1))).
```

I found that my wordnetsubsumes just check the first word and I am not sure if it check for the list or not in my code.

BY THE WAY, I am using sicstus prolog if there is some different between it and SWI in this code.

Comment: what `\+list()` does ?

Comment: I would like to say make sure that it is not a list, maybe I am wrong

Comment: that could be your problem then: change the clause to `wordnetsubsumes(H0, H1):- \+list(H0), ...`

Comment: overall, the test seems useless to me: s(I,_,H0,_,_,_) will **surely** fail if H0 is a list

Comment: I delete it +/list, it seems to me is fine, but as you said, cannot work with nested list so it might work with 
`subsynset([like, john, mary], [love, john, mary]).` but not with `subsynset([like, [john], mary], [love, [john, mary]]).`